# exiftool-vendored doesn't return when used in an electron app on Mac?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, exiftool

On Mac, when I run my app from WebStorm, exiftool-vendored works great.  However, when I build my app (I use electron-builder) and install it on the same Mac, it never returns, even just trying to get the version:

`exiftool.version().then(version => writeBreadcrumb('exif', version))`

In other words, no error is raised, and the `then` is never executed when running an installed version of my app, though it works fine running my app from WebStorm (with `cd build && electron .`)

What am I doing wrong?  Is there an example anywhere of how to use exiftool-vendored in an electron app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at what the docs say about making it work with Electron:

> #### How do you make this work with electron?
>
> Electron is notoriously brittle and buggy, and is not officially supported by this package. Although PhotoStructure uses this package within electron, there's a nontrivial amount of auxiliary support code specific to that project to make it work smoothly.
>
> If you're still anxious to try, here are some things to keep in mind:
>
> 1. Note that this package will spawn exiftool external processes, which means the exiftool-vendored.pl and exiftool-vendored.exe packages should be included in your asarUnpack. SmartUnpack might work, but if it doesn't use a pattern like `node_modules/{exiftool-vendored.*}/**/*`.
> 2. If you're requiring exiftool-vendored from within a webview, you're gonna have a bad time. Many things won't work due to a lack of node compatibility within electron.
> 3. `__dirname` at runtime from within an asar package after webpacking will be invalid, so don't rely on that.
>
> — https://github.com/photostructure/exiftool-vendored.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-you-make-this-work-with-electron

Comment: Thanks very much!  That is really helpful to know.  Wish I'd seen that long ago.

Answer (score 3):

Since I never found a way to get `exiftool-vendored` to work with electron on Mac, I accepted the above answer, as essentially a warning to steer clear of `exiftool-vendored` for electron on Mac.

This answer is included for completeness, for those of us who need [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) in an electron app for both Mac and Windows:

I used [node-exiftool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-exiftool) with these settings added in package.json for electron-builder:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "win": {
    ...
    "extraResources": "exiftoolwin/**/*"
  },
  "mac": {
    ...
    "extraResources": "exiftool/**/*"
  }
}
```

In the root of my project, I added folders `exiftoolwin` and `exiftool`.  In `exiftoolwin`, I put `exiftool.exe` which I obtained by following the Windows Stand-Alone Executable instructions [here](https://exiftool.org/install.html), and in my `exiftool` folder I put `exiftool` and `lib` which I obtained by extracting the full perl distribution on Mac, as described on the same page.

Then, in my .jsx (I'm using React):

```
import exiftool from 'node-exiftool';
const exiftoolFolderAndFile = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'exiftoolwin/exiftool.exe' : 'exiftool/exiftool';
const exiftoolPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', exiftoolFolderAndFile);
const ep = new exiftool.ExiftoolProcess(exiftoolPath);
```

Then I just use `ep` as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-exiftool).

Comment: Thanks so much, David! You are a life-saver!

Answer (score 1):

This is working for us:

add this dependency:

```
"exiftool-vendored": "^15.2.0",
```

Update package.json "build" section for mac ( not needed for windows as far as we can see )

```
"build": {
  "mac": {
    ...
    "asarUnpack": [
       "node_modules/exiftool-vendored/**" ,
       "node_modules/exiftool-vendored.pl/**"
    ]
  }
}
```